# How to setup virtual users for vsftpd with access to a specific sub directory?

Tags: server, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I need to be able to add a virtual users to vsftpd that only have access to a sub folder. The reason why I want to use virtual users is I only want to have 1 real user on the server.

The FTP structure is:

- `www`

  - `website_name1`

    - ***`sub_folder1`***
  - `website_name2`

    - `sub_folder2`
    - ***`sub_folder3`***
  - `website_name3`
  - `website_name4`

The main account has access to the www folder and all sub directories and I want to add a virtual user that can have access to the **sub_folder1** and only **sub_folder1**

Also to avoid some confusion I would also require another user to access **sub_folder3** and only **sub_folder3**. My point being I need to be able to choose which folder and sub folders on a user by user basis.

I have found ways to to add users to see the whole strucutre or setup user named folders both of which have no use to me.

I found a similar question posted here:

[How to setup VSFTPD for multiple users including adding specific directories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73323/how-to-setup-vsftpd-for-multiple-users-including-adding-specific-directories)

but it recommends `proftpd` which I though was general less secure.
Or have I missed the point here?

Comment: I had a problem with authentication for the longest time until I found this http://serverfault.com/questions/450214/vsftpd-will-not-accept-passwords-encrypted-with-md5 Apparently PAM has issues with MD5 hash. This guide solves that issue.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

With a bit of playing around I've managed to come up with a semi solution (not perfect but good enough)

using 2707974 answer and information I've gained else where I've been able to get what I need.

First you need vsftp and PAM installed

```
apt-get install vsftpd libpam-pwdfile
```

**Edit /etc/vsftpd.conf**

```
nano /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

then paste in the following

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
local_root=/var/www
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
hide_ids=YES

#virutal user settings
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd_user_conf
guest_enable=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
nopriv_user=vsftpd
guest_username=vsftpd
```

Edit to your exact needs the most important bit for virtual users is everything after the virtual user settings comment

**Creating User**

You can either use a database or `htpasswd` I found `htpasswd` faster and easier to use.

make a directory to store your users

```
mkdir /etc/vsftpd
htpasswd -cd /etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd user1
```

adding additional users just omit the `-c`

```
htpasswd -d /etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd user2
```

**I've only managed to get it to work using CRYPT which limits to 8 chars**
**to use more than 8 chars use openssl to generate a compatible hash and pipe directly into htpasswd**

```
htpasswd -c -p -b /etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd user1 $(openssl passwd -1 -noverify password)
```

Once your users are created you can now change your PAM config file

```
nano /etc/pam.d/vsftpd
```

and remove everything inside this file and replace with the following

```
auth required pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile /etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd
account required pam_permit.so
```

**This will enable login for your virtual users defined in `/etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd` and will disable local users**

Next we need to add a user for these virtual users to use. These users will not have access to the shell and will be called `vsftpd`

```
useradd --home /home/vsftpd --gid nogroup -m --shell /bin/false vsftpd
```

the user must match `guest_username=vsftpd` in the vsftpd conf file

**Defining Directory Access**

The important line here is the following

```
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd_user_conf
```

this means that when `user1` logs in it will look for the following file

```
/etc/vsftpd_user_conf/user1
```

this file the same as the `vsftpd.conf` so you can define a new `local_root`

going back to the question we want `user1` to only have access to `var/www/website_name1/sub_folder1`, so we need to create the `vsftpd_user_conf` folder:

```
mkdir /etc/vsftpd_user_conf
```

Now create the user file:

```
nano /etc/vsftpd_user_conf/user1
```

and enter the following line

```
local_root=/var/www/website_name1/sub_folder1
```

Now restart vsftp

```
service vsftpd restart
```

you should now be able to login as user1 who will only be able to see 
`var/www/website_name1/sub_folder1` and any folder and file inside it.

That's it you can now add as many users as you want and limit their access to whatever folder you wish.

**important to remember if you do not create a user conf file it will default to the var/www folder as root (in the example above)**

If the subfolder is intended to be modifiable by the user, it might be necesary to change the owner of the shared subfolder:

```
chown vsftpd:nogroup /var/www/website_name1/sub_folder1
```

Comment: This works with some modifications: 1) Use absolute paths (replace paths starting on "var/" with "/var". 2) vsftpd 2.3.5 which is in Ubuntu 12.04 does not support allow_writeable_chroot option, you can solve it by [installing patched vsftpd](http://askubuntu.com/a/257239/110375).

Comment: Hello, with the ssl password do we again omit -c with -d or just omit -c? Also on a second note, do we just rerun the query to change the password? or is there another method. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to create a home directory with useradd --home? it is necessary?

Comment: Additional: enable secure TLS connections. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-vsftpd-to-use-ssl-tls-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Comment: apache2-utils might be required for some installations  I have not included it in the answers since its not relevant for everyone.

Comment: I am getting the response `500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/var/www/html/websites/equality_streets` when trying to FTP connect... Does the user 'vsftpd' need to be added to the 'www-data' group? I notice when I do `chown vsftpd:nogroup /var/www/website_name1/sub_folder1` I can no longer access the website

Comment: Conntecting via FTP shouldn't have anything to do with the www-data group. The error could be for multple reasons most likely is SELinux rather than permissions on the folder. Though try removing the user config and put the address directly into the config so that is starts in that folder and see if it throws the same error.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/174235/500-oops-cannot-change-directory-home-user-public-html-vsftpd-error

Comment: @Avenyet I am not sure I understand. I commented out the "virtual user settings" in the config and then tried signing in as 'vsftpd', but it states "530 Login incorrect" when providing the correct password set via the 'passwd' command

Comment: Very elegant and great solution. Thanks to @2707974 as well.

Comment: For FTP over nat, read: http://www.devops-blog.net/iptables/iptables-rules-for-nat-with-ftp-active-passive and http://www.devops-blog.net/iptables/iptables-rules-for-nat-with-ftp-active-passive

Comment: @Avenyet I have followed all the steps, but i keep getting the following in Filezilla: 530 permission denied. could not connect to server

Comment: For create second user don't use the `-c` parameter. It's creating file again.

`htpasswd -p -b /etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd user2 $(openssl passwd -1 -noverify password)`

Comment: It is possible to generate stronger hashes using the `mkpasswd` command. See my answer below.

Comment: You should add `apache2-utils` to the first `apt install` line, it is required for the htpasswd command

Answer (score 14):

Try with this manual. Maybe will work for You.

How to do it

Install vsftpd and a PAM library

Edit `/etc/vsftpd.conf` and `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd`

Create user accouts with custom directories (in /var/www/ for example)

Set directories with the correct `chmod` and `chown`

Create a admin user with full access to the server

1. Install `vsftpd` (Very Secure FTP Deamon) and `libpam-pwdfile` to create virtual users

I wanted to create FTP users but I didn’t want to add local unix users (no shell access, no home directory and so on). A PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules) will help you create virtual users.

`sudo apt-get install vsftpd libpam-pwdfile`

2. Edit `vsftpd.conf`

First you need to back up the original file

`sudo mv /etc/vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd.conf.bak`

Then create a new one

`sudo vim /etc/vsftpd.conf`

Copy and paste the following lines. The file should ONLY contain these lines:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
nopriv_user=vsftpd
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
guest_enable=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/var/www/$USER
chroot_local_user=YES
hide_ids=YES
guest_username=vsftpd
```

3. Register virtual users

To register a user you use `htpasswd`, so I assume you have `apache2` working on your 
server. Create a `vsftpd` folder then put configuration files in it.

`sudo mkdir /etc/vsftpd`

then

`sudo htpasswd -cd /etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd user1`

-c means that we’ll create the file if it’s not existing yet
-d forces MD5, you need it on ubuntu 12.04, just use it always

The command will prompt for a password.

If you want to add new users afterwards:

`sudo htpasswd -d /etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd user2`

4. Configure PAM in `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd`

Again, you need to back up the orignal file

`sudo mv /etc/pam.d/vsftpd /etc/pam.d/vsftpd.bak`

and create a new one

`sudo vim /etc/pam.d/vsftpd`

Copy and paste these 2 lines (this should be the only content). I insist only these 2 lines, I wasted a lot of time keeping the originals and just added these.

```
auth required pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile /etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd
account required pam_permit.so
```

5. Create a local user without shell access

`sudo useradd --home /home/vsftpd --gid nogroup -m --shell /bin/false vsftpd`

You can check that it’s been created with the id command: id vsftpd. We define the user with the /bin/false shell because of the check_shell parameter (even if you don’t use it). When the end user connects to the FTP server, they will be used for rights and ownership:

`chmod` and `chown`.

6. Restart `vsftpd`

The common way is using init.d like all deamon

`sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart`

`sudo service vsftpd restart`

7. Create directories

According to configuration all users will be placed into this folder: /var/www/user1.

You need to create them with particular rights: the root folder cannot be writable!

```
 / [root = /var/www/user1] => 555
www [ /var/www/user1/www ] => 755
docs [ /var/www/user1/docs ] => 755
```

Note: the user cannot create files or folders in the root directory.

In `vsftpd.conf` we have `chroot_local_user=YES` so the user can’t see anything outside of his folder. To him, the server looks like this:

So just run these commands:

```
mkdir /var/www/user1`
chmod -w /var/www/user1
mkdir www/user1/www
chmod -R 755 /var/www/user1/www
chown -R vsftpd:nogroup /var/www/user1
```

The `/var/www/user1` folder HAS TO exist or connection will fail.

Right now you can try to connect with your FTP

8. Create an Admin user to access the entire server

To create an admin user we need to register a new user with `htpasswd`.

Before we do so, I’ll advise you to check into the `/etc/ftpusers` file that define certain users that are not allowed to connect with ftp. I think it’s only for local users and not virtual users but just in case don’t choose a name contained in this file.

`sudo htpasswd -d /etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd theadmin`

Now we need to add a new line into `/etc/vsftpd.conf`

`chroot_list_enable=YES`

This means that your user will be placed into their folder (as a jail) EXCEPT users in the /etc/

`vsftpd.chroot_list`

Let’s create this file and add our user, the file is a simple line containing “theadmin”. Add one user per line. That means you DON’T need to create a `/var/www/theadmin` folder, the user will login and start in `/home/vsftpd`.

Restart the server and you’re done !

Comment: Tried this already it very inflexible since it enforces local_root=/var/www/$USER. It doesn't allow me to specify a single directory for a user or users. this directory normally has different purpose and location depending on the client. Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers by @Avenyet and @2707974, you can use a more secure way to create the virtual users password file (`/etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd`). In stead of using the `htaccess` command you can use the `mkpasswd` command from the `whois` package (on Ubuntu at least). `mkpasswd` doesn't update the password file for you like `htaccess`, it only generates a password hash. So you will need to create and update the password file yourself.

Fortunately the password file syntax is very simple, it just consists of the username and password hash separated by a colon, and one line for each user. Example:

```
user1:6Gshac7jdk01U
```

This is the password `foo`, with the basic crypt hashing.

Linux crypt supports better hashing algorithms than the basic des crypt used by `htaccess` and the md5 used by the `openssl passwd` command. Use `mkpasswd -m help` to see a list of which algorithms your `crypt` supports. On today's systems the best ones are SHA-256 or SHA-512. Unlike default des crypt hashing (which `htaccess` also uses) these make use of all the characters in the password, and unlike des and `openssl passwd` they have a configurable number of rounds.

The more rounds, the longer it takes to calculate the hash, and the more difficult it becomes to reverse the hash if an attacker gains access to the password hashes. For a server that is not on the public internet I would say to pick the number of rounds as high as possible but without the hashing taking noticeable time, so less than 0.1 second. If the server is on the internet, that might become a denial of service vector, as someone could try lots of logins with random passwords and use up CPU resources. If that is a risk for your configuration you should use a lower value.

The default for the SHA variants is 5000, which is pretty low. I'm using 100000 on my installation (which is not publicly accessible).

To generate such a hash, enter `mkpasswd -m sha-512 -R 100000`. This will ask you to enter the password and print out the hash. Use the hash in the passwd file instead of the simple crypt hashes like this:

```
user1:$6$rounds=100000$HRZdUPD8$GVBmHg91rjNm.WlcMCcLp41Ewz6XXJ1ktKzS8Zmr8cmyVGR28URVY1A9N3Nz4W9zl6lDGjwVbz94N/JQVSGOh/
```

The type of hash and the number of rounds is embedded in the hash value, so `crypt` can see what method to use to check a password. It is even possible to mix different types of hashes in a single passwd file. These passwd files can be used at `/etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd` for the highest level of security `crypt` currently has to offer. For the rest of the configuration I refer to the other answers.

(I'm still waiting for `crypt` to support a better password hashing algorithm like scrypt or one of the Argon2 variants.)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, and for flexibility create a userconfig dir and file,
 `mkdir /var/www/userconfs` or whatever you want to change the userconfs name to, then create a specific file

```
vi /var/www/userconfigs/ftpuseraccount
```

inside type, `local_root=/var/www`(or whatever u want to access by dir)
`guest_username=www-data`(the ubuntu owner of the file top edit

after update you vsftpd.conf by adding `user_config_dir=/var/www/userconfigs`(or whatever you replaced it as, this account will access whatever sdir yo specified)