# No write access for vsFTPd server despite 777 permissions on files

Tags: server, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I followed [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/a/575825) in order to set up a vsFTPd server on my Raspberry Pi.

Currently I am able to read files without any problem but trying to write gives me this error from Firezilla

> 550 Permission Denied

I have tried changing the file to `777` permissions to see if I can open it at all but I'm getting the same 550 Permission Denied error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Just to follow up in case anyone stumbles upon this. The `vsftpd.conf` file has to have the following line added:

```
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
```